# Какой тип checked exception указывать в интерфейсе?

Tags: java, исключения, интерфейс, проектирование

В книге Clean Code (Чистый Код) в главе 17 описан smell (запашок) G6: Code at Wrong Level of Abstraction.

```
public interface Stack {
    Object pop() throws EmptyException;
    void push(Object o) throws FullException;
    double percentFull();
    class EmptyException extends Exception {}
    class FullException extends Exception {}
}
```

В этом интерфейсе метод `percentFull` явно лишний, т. к. класс стека, реализующий его, может не иметь заданной ёмкости. С этим всё понятно, удаляём метод из интерфейса.

Однако, метод `push` может бросать исключение `FullException`, которое, аналогично, не имеет смысла, если реализация стека boundless (безразмерная).

Собственно, вопрос: что делать с этим исключением в Java? В книге ничего по этому поводу не сказано. Я не нашёл обсуждений этого вопроса. Следует ли в интерфейсе заменить исключение на более общее `Exception` и, соответственно, полностью убрать `FullException`?

В языках, где не нужно указывать выбрасываемые исключения, такого вопроса не возникает.

Comment: Пока формулировал и писал вопрос, сам осознал ответ. И можно было бы его уже не задавать, но несколько удивляет, что в книге упущен этот момент, так что дам возможность желающим блеснуть знаниями.